# Passing different inputs into overloaded functions

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to pass user input into an overloaded function, but one functions needs a string and the other needs an int, is there a way to just pass in the user input without having to do ifs to check if its a string or int and then having to different call lines?

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Comment: Isn't user input *always* a string?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Cannot tell any more details without looking at your code.

Comment: @KerrekSB - usually a tissue of lies

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways to apporach your problem

**1: using the template typename**

```
template <typename T>
void print(T input){
   cout<<input<<endl; 
}
```

**2: You can use the overloaded functions**

```
void print(int input){
   cout<<input<<endl; 
}
void print(double input){
   cout<<input<<endl; 
}
```

Good Luck